# Skype API URI Capture

Tags: javascript, jquery, skype, skype-for-business

I have downloaded code from internet which is able to create meetings on behalf of anonymous users with skype for business. When I click the chat button this following function is called which in turns create a meeting URL. My problem is i am not able to crack the meeting URL, means how this function is able to create the URL. I am pasting the snippet of the code. Can someone please tell me how it is able to generate that URL.

```
$('#startNewChatMeeting').click(function () {
        var conv, dfd, meetingUri;
        conv = client.conversationsManager.createConversation();
        $('#newMeetingUri').val("");
        dfd = conv.chatService.start().then(function () {
            meetingUri = conv.uri();
            $('#newMeetingUri').val(meetingUri);
            $(".c-add-p-container").removeClass('hide');
        });
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? To create the URI by yourself?
This is done in the 'client.conversationsManager.createConversation()' whatever it is...

Comment: I want to capture that URL, that random URL which it is generating and connecting the meeting.

Comment: The URI should be in the variable "meetingUri" or am I missing something?

Comment: No You are right, My Problem is I want to capture that URI. Basically that URI is filled inside newMeetingUri textBox as seen in code. but i am not able to track how to control over that URI. If you want more elaboration I can provide you with the whole Code.

Comment: I don't get what you want to do. What do you want to do with the "captured" URI?
You have it in the variable "meetingUri", so you can do with this URI what you want and what is possible in JavaScript.